# PHP beautifier/tidier/cleaner written in JavaScript

Tags: library, javascript, code-beautification

The title says it all, I'm looking for a library or some piece of JavaScript code to beautify PHP code. (would be good if it could also tidy HTML or JavaScript but not necessarily)

Does anyone know such a library?

Comment: Do you care about pricing? how about server-side (ie Node.js) or client side (ie browser)?

Comment: @NickWilde I'm actually looking for a free tool (just a spare time project) and it should be useable on client side. (node.js library is okay as long as it is 100% JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seemed like there was no such library so I've written one myself. You can find it here:

https://github.com/idmean/nowClean

I've also written about it on my blog:

http://www.zujab.at/2014/09/nowclean-clean-your-code/